# Searching for text in excel

Tags: excel

I want to count the number of occurrences of a specific text string inside a range of cells in excel. Some cells contain only one word but others contain multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

use countif function --------------> `=COUNTIF(range,criteria)`

you pass the text string as a criteria put it in quotes.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(range,"*" & criteria & "*")` works even if cells have multiple words. It will not distinguish between "cat" and "catatonic" though.

Answer (score 0):

A1:A3: Cells with text strings
C1: Word searched

We can use an array formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter from formula window, curled brackets are inserted by Excel itself):

```
   ={(SUM(LEN(A1:A3))-SUM(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,$C$1,""))))/LEN($C$1)}
```

The searched word is deleted from the initial set of strings, which shortens by n*length.